# Defining a Foreign key constraint in H2 Databases on table that has 2 column primary key

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, h2

I have table with 2 columns primary key.
I wont to create foreign key on that table from other table.

```
CREATE TABLE MESSAGING.RECIPIENT (
TYPE VARCHAR NOT NULL,
SERIAL_NUMBER VARCHAR NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_RECIPIENT PRIMARY KEY (TYPE,SERIAL_NUMBER)
);
```

I am trying something like that:

```
CREATE TABLE MESSAGING.MESSAGE (
    ID VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    RECIPIENT_ID BIGINT,
    MESSAGE_VALID_FROM TIMESTAMP,
    CONSTRAINT PK_MESSAGE PRIMARY KEY (ID),
    CONSTRAINT MESSAGE_FK FOREIGN KEY (RECIPIENT_ID,RECIPIENT_ID) REFERENCES MESSAGING.RECIPIENT(TYPE,SERIAL_NUMBER)
);
```

but seems not to work
Is it even possible?

Comment: if you are getting any error message , please add it your question, however what you are doing its a strange thing. what are you trying to do?

Comment: You can reference a two-column primary key only with two different columns of the same or compatible data types. You can't repeat the same column multiple times in constraint definition.

Answer (score 0):

If i got your doubt appropriately.

You can something like:

```
CREATE TABLE MESSAGING.RECIPIENT (
TYPE VARCHAR NOT NULL,
SERIAL_NUMBER VARCHAR NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE MESSAGING.RECIPIENT ADD PRIMARY KEY (TYPE,SERIAL_NUMBER);
```

In the other table where you want to do a reference of `MESSAGE.RECIPIENT`, you have to add both fields in order to get the foreign key; you can do this:

```
CREATE TABLE MESSAGING.MESSAGE (
    ID VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    RECIPIENT_TYPE VARCHAR,
    RECIPIENT_SERIAL_NUMBER VARCHAR,
    MESSAGE_VALID_FROM TIMESTAMP
);

ALTER TABLE MESSAGING.MESSAGE ADD PRIMARY KEY(ID);
ALTER TABLE MESSAGING.MESSAGE ADD FOREIGN KEY(RECIPIENT_TYPE,RECIPIENT_SERIAL_NUMBER) REFERENCES MESSAGING.RECIPIENT(TYPE,SERIAL_NUMBER);
```

Cheers.